# How to restrict/disable `Remove User` option from shared workbook , Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook that is shared between users (Office 2016).
I need to restrict/disable `Remove User` option from shared workbook.
**Meaning** `only I am allowed to use this option.`
I searched every where before post this question , but in vain.
**UserStatus** [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus) **array** is the responsible about shared users.

**Note**: I do not mean to control others can do on their computer. I mean only prevent current users whom opened that workbook to not remove any existing user by mistake. I already have codes on this workbook to `disable Save As` (`only @ this workbook`)

as always, your support is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can do it by customizing your ribbon, enabling or disabling controls and groups. Take a look at Ron de Bruin web site, in particlar to this [Link](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm).

Comment: @Elio Fernandes actually, I need to disable it for other users side ,Like disable SaveAsUI and disable insert new Sheet .

Comment: Have you considered that it is just not possible? Typically you do not get the option to control what others can do on their computer. Also, it seems that Shared Workbooks are being phased out and replaced with "Co-Authoring" - that might be worth looking into... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534

Comment: @braX I do not mean to control others can do on their computer. I only prevent current users whom opened that workbook to not remove any existing user by mistake. I already have codes on this workbook to `disable Save As` (**only @ this workbook**)

Comment: @braX concerning "Co-Authoring" , it is only available with `Office 365` , and my company use office 2016 .

Comment: If you want to enable\disable keyboard functionality, you can use ``Application.Onkey`` method, but you need to be careful. You need to ensure that the keyboard shortcuts that you disable will be enabled on exiting or deactivating the workbook. If later a user complains that some of the keyboards do not work in another excel workbook while this workbook is closed, you'll have to delete the default Excel template ``Excel15.xlb`` locate in ``%appdata%Microsoft\Excel``. It will be created automatically when you start Excel again.

Comment: As this tagged as vba, one assumes you're looking for a vba solution. If that's so: Generally speaking, if you can’t do something it via the user interfaces, you can't do it in vba. I did some general checking, and that certainly seems to be the case here. So I'd support @braX and also suggest it simply isn't possible via vba. If you're not looking for vba solution, you should probably deleted this and ask here: [Super user](https://superuser.com). Though, to be honest, I'd expect the same outcome there.

Comment: @Spinner I posted also on Super user, actually I need an answer by Vba or not , But I will keep it here , maybe someone can guide.